# Problem with programmatic navigation in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, router

I'm developing a Vue.js application and there is something that I can't figure out about programmatic navigation.
As you can see below in my index.js file I have a tree structured routes in my client, some of this route need to be protected.
The routes that must be protected are the ones that are child of 'dashboard'.

When the App is loaded, if the user try to navigate one of those protected routes, the client send a request to the server, asking if the token that he possess allow him to access those protected routes, if the answer is yes then the user can freely navigate, otherwise I want to redirect him to the login page.

The problem arise here, how you can see from the 'App.vue' if the request checkSession fail (meaning no valid token has been provided) the error will be catched and `this.$router.push('/login')` is executed, but without success, in fact the url does not change at all.

I tried to print the `router` object and I have noticed that the route that I'm trying to push appear under `history.pending` properties of the cited object.[image]

Another weird thing that I've noticed: if I delete the redirect in the routes path (the very last one) declared in the 'index.js' file  and I load the App through an url that does not belong to one of the declared routes, for example '/wrong/path', and the user does not provide a valid token then `$router.push('/login')` works fine.

index.js

```
...

const routes = [{
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'dashboard',
    redirect : '/dipendenti/aggiungi',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'dipendenti', component: MiddleWareComponent, children:[
        { path: 'aggiungi', component: AddWorkerComponent },
        { path: 'elimina', component: DeleteWorkerComponent },
        { path: 'modifica', component: ModifyWorkerComponent }
      ]},
      { path: 'clienti', component: MiddleWareComponent, children:[
        { path: 'aggiungi', component: AddClientComponent },
        { path: 'modifica', component: ModifyClientComponent }
      ]},
      { path: 'team', component: MiddleWareComponent, children:[
        { path: 'aggiungi', component: AddTeamComponent },
        { path: 'elimina', component: DeleteTeamComponent },
        { path: 'modifica', component: ModifyTeamComponent }
      ]},
      { path: 'lavori', component: MiddleWareComponent, children:[
        { path: 'visualizza', component: ViewWorkComponent },
        { path: 'aggiungi', component: AddWorkComponent },
        { path: 'elimina', component: DeleteWorkComponent },
        { path: 'modifica', component: ModifyWorkComponent }
      ]},
      { path: 'account', component: MiddleWareComponent, children:[
        { path: 'modifica', component: ModifyAccountComponent }
      ]}
    ]
  },
  { path: '/logout', component: LogoutComponent },
  { path: '/password-forgot', component: PasswordForgotComponent },
  { path: '/password-reset/:token/:api', component: PasswordResetComponent },
  { path: '/*', redirect : '/' }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: routes,
  base: __dirname,
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  mode: 'history'
});

...
```

App.vue

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';


Vue.prototype.$https = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000',
  withCredentials: true,
  crossdomain: true
});

Vue.prototype.$checkSession = function() {
  if (window.location.pathname != '/login' && window.location.pathname != '/password-forgot' && window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] != 'password-reset') {
    var authToken = localStorage.authToken? localStorage.authToken:sessionStorage.authToken;
    this.$https.defaults.headers.common['x-csrf-token'] = authToken;
    this.$https.get('api/web/user/session').then(response => {
      if(window.location.pathname == '/'){
        this.$router.push('/dipendenti/aggiungi');
      }
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(this.$router.app);
      this.$router.push('/login');
    })
  }
}

...


export default {
  name: 'app',
  created: function() {
    this.$checkSession();
  }
};
</script>
```

The desired behavior would be the redirect to the login page.

Comment: I would recommend adding a `meta` field of `requiresAuth: true` as described here:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html
I think this will achieve your desired result.